# How to split the Regular Expression using delimiters

Tags: string, delimiter

How to split the following String using delimiters

```
 ( (2.1 * 5 / 2   ) - -2   +  (  18+9) / 3  )
```

I want to get the output as

Operator Array :[  ( , ( , * , / , ) , - , + , ( , + , ) , / , )  ]

Operands:[ 2.1 , 5 , 2 , -2 , 18 , 9 ,3  ]

Answer (score 0):

I think the RegExp will have hard time to handle this string because you have to cover all possibilities. I suggest to try it by using RegExp to put comma sign after each character and then use conditional expressions to handle all possibilites. I think this will be a loooooooooooong RegExp.

Maybe it would be easier to handle the string in the for loop. Here you can easily check next and previous element when using index.

Best regards.

EDIT:

It seems that I misunderstood... Here is my edit.

You can do it with for loop and just handle specific use cases with if statements. For instance, if current element is number you can check if next element (by checking index + 1) is a number and do this until you find the character that is not a number and saved number add to new string. Of course, when you check you should have a variable to save result which you want to add to new string.